# How do you decode Base64 data in Python?

Tags: python, base64, decode

I have the following piece of Base64 encoded data, and I want to use the Python Base64 module to extract information from it. It seems that module does not work. How can I make it work?

```
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
```

Comment: Can you expand on the problem you're having? I just used `base64.b64decode` to decode it fine...

Comment: what is your method please? Did you use base64.b64decode(string) ?

Comment: I use it too, but I did not understand the result

Comment: The result will vary depending on what's supposed to be inside. I've looked at the result, but I don't understand it too. Where did you get the encoded data? What was it supposed to be?

Comment: The result is... difficult to post here. It begins:
`C\x96\x00\n\x00\x00\x00\x00C\x96\x00\x1b\x00\x00\x00`

Comment: I think the result should be a series of coordinates, such as (x, y, z), with different values

Comment: Yes, exactlly, the result is as what you posted

Comment: but it appears that when concatenating the encoded strings, the decode will not work in a correct way, that means, the result would probably look rather messy, like C\x96\x00\n\x00\x00\x00\x00C....

Comment: so how am i gonna see what is within this piece of data?

Comment: @ladyfafa, I don't know what to tell you. You were given a piece of data that was encoded in base64, and you know how to decode the string to get the original data - after that, you still have to understand the format of the data in order to be able to interpret it. Without giving us more information about the results, it's very difficult to tell you what to do with it. Even knowing that it's a series of coordinates isn't that helpful without knowing (for example) if they're 4 byte integers, or floats or what. Can you not get this information from the source of the data? Then we could help.

Comment: @Blair, thank you, I would like to post a piece of code here, but it seems to be too long, or I don't know how to change it, could you please let me know your email or I could send it to you then? thanks again

Comment: Or how could make this clear? I mean, to deal with what this encoded data?

Comment: or you could please send it to my email ladyfafa@hotmail.com, thanks!!

Comment: @ladyfafa Is it packed binary data?  Python module `struct` can parse out strings to values *if you know the format*, though you might be able to guess.  What gave you this string?

Comment: @Nick T, thanks, I tried the struct module, but still no clues... nor do I know the format of this encoded string...

Comment: it might be a binary data, what I know is that the data comprise of coordinates...

Comment: could you please tell me what I might try?

Comment: What gave you this data?

Comment: @ Nick T, the same thing, could I ask you via email, seems the code can not work fine here, let me if it is okay?? thanks

Comment: I mean where did this data come from?  Did your cat type it for you?  Did you convert a bitmap into a string?  Did program XYZ output it?

Comment: yes, a software deals with this data, but the user did not know how this software might work, i mean, it is a black box ...

Comment: Did the black box give all that data at the same time or did it break it up into smaller messages?

Comment: the user just need to select the working directory, click on "load data" button, then after serveral minutes, everything was done, such as analysis, display, etc. that's all I know what this software :(

Comment: 22016 characters. Can't it be made shorter?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because decoding arbitrary data streams is not what Stack Overflow is for. Despite the literal question, the question is really about the interpretation of the data after it has been Base64-decode. This is revealed in comments to [Nick T's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470546/how-do-you-decode-base64-data-in-python/3471231#3471231) (the only real comprehensive answer).

Answer (score 418):

```
import base64
coded_string = '''Q5YACgA...'''
base64.b64decode(coded_string)
```

worked for me. At the risk of pasting an offensively-long result, I got:

```
>>> base64.b64decode(coded_string)
2: 'C\x96\x00\n\x00\x00\x00\x00C\x96\x00\x1b\x00\x00\x00\x00C\x96\x00-\x00\x00\x00\x00C\x96\x00?\x00\x00\x00\x00C\x96\x07M\x00\x00\x00\x00C\x96\x07_\x00\x00\x00\x00C\x96\x07p\x00\x00\x00\x00C\x96\x07\x82\x00\x00\x00\x00C\x96\x07\x94\x00\x00\x00\x00C\x96\x07\xa6Cq\xf0\x7fC\x96\x07\xb8DJ\x81\xc7C\x96\x07\xcaD\xa5\x9dtC\x96\x07\xdcD\xb6\x97\x11C\x96\x07\xeeD\x8b\x8flC\x96\x07\xffD\x03\xd4\xaaC\x96\x08\x11B\x05&\xdcC\x96\x08#\x00\x00\x00\x00C\x96\x085C\x0c\xc9\xb7C\x96\x08GCy\xc0\xebC\x96\x08YC\x81\xa4xC\x96\x08kC\x0f@\x9bC\x96\x08}\x00\x00\x00\x00C\x96\x08\x8e\x00\x00\x00\x00C\x96\x08\xa0\x00\x00\x00\x00C\x96\x08\xb2\x00\x00\x00\x00C\x96\x86\xf9\x00\x00\x00\x00C\x96\x87\x0b\x00\x00\x00\x00C\x96\x87\x1d\x00\x00\x00\x00C\x96\x87/\x00\x00\x00\x00C\x96\x87AA\x0b\xe7PC\x96\x87SCI\xf5gC\x96\x87eC\xd4J\xeaC\x96\x87wD\r\x17EC\x96\x87\x89D\x00F6C\x96\x87\x9bC\x9cg\xdeC\x96\x87\xadB\xd56\x0cC\x96\x87\xbf\x00\x00\x00\x00C\x96\x87\xd1\x00\x00\x00\x00C\x96\x87\xe3\x00\x00\x00\x00C\x96\x87\xf5\x00\x00\x00\x00C\x9cY}\x00\x00\x00\x00C\x9cY\x90\x00\x00\x00\x00C\x9cY\xa4\x00\x00\x00\x00C\x9cY\xb7\x00\x00\x00\x00C\x9cY\xcbC\x1f\xbd\xa3C\x9cY\xdeCCz{C\x9cY\xf1CD\x02\xa7C\x9cZ\x05C+\x9d\x97C\x9cZ\x18C\x03R\xe3C\x9cZ,\x00\x00\x00\x00C\x9cZ?
[stuff omitted as it exceeded SO's body length limits]
\xbb\x00\x00\x00\x00D\xc5!7\x00\x00\x00\x00D\xc5!\xb2\x00\x00\x00\x00D\xc7\x14x\x00\x00\x00\x00D\xc7\x14\xf6\x00\x00\x00\x00D\xc7\x15t\x00\x00\x00\x00D\xc7\x15\xf2\x00\x00\x00\x00D\xc7\x16pC5\x9f\xf9D\xc7\x16\xeeC[\xb5\xf5D\xc7\x17lCG\x1b;D\xc7\x17\xeaB\xe3\x0b\xa6D\xc7\x18h\x00\x00\x00\x00D\xc7\x18\xe6\x00\x00\x00\x00D\xc7\x19d\x00\x00\x00\x00D\xc7\x19\xe2\x00\x00\x00\x00D\xc7\xfe\xb4\x00\x00\x00\x00D\xc7\xff3\x00\x00\x00\x00D\xc7\xff\xb2\x00\x00\x00\x00D\xc8\x001\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

Comment: I have exactlly the same process as you did, but what are the results ?

Comment: This is pretty old but I think their issue was the above is it doesn't print anything. I assume print base64.b64decode(coded_string) was what they were looking for. Thanks for the simple example it helped me!

Comment: I get an error: ~"**partially initialized module 'base64' has no attribute 'b64decode'**"

Comment: why this looks like : \xbb\x00\x00\x00\x00D\x ......................
Instead of a string?

Comment: because it's a whole bunch of bytes, not a string. b64decode decodes to a bunch of bytes. There's no reason to believe that it would be a string (even if you knew what encoding)

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky this has **nothing to do with** the `base64` module. Please read: [Importing a library from (or near) a script with the same name raises "AttributeError: module has no attribute" or an ImportError or NameError](/q/36250353/).

Comment: @Shax I don't really know what string you expect it to look like instead, or why; nor am I sure what you think strings "look like", or why this "doesn't" look like one. My best guess is that you do not properly understand what bytes are and what data is, and the fact that simply not every sequence of bytes is "readable". Please try reading [What do files actually contain, and how are they "read"? What is a "format" and why should I worry about them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75078605).

Answer (score 219):

## Python 3 (and 2)

```
import base64
a = 'eW91ciB0ZXh0'
base64.b64decode(a)
```

## Python 2

A quick way to decode it without importing anything:

```
'eW91ciB0ZXh0'.decode('base64')
```

or more descriptive

```
>>> a = 'eW91ciB0ZXh0'
>>> a.decode('base64')
'your text'
```

Comment: Btw this also works for *encoding* >>> `'your text'.encode('base64')`

Comment: First part of the answer is slightly misleading. Python 3 and 2 don't produce same output for `base64.b64decode(a)`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63056193/base64-b64decode-output-differences-python-2-vs-python-3

Comment: *This whole answer

Answer (score 82):

**Base64 encode/decode example:**

```
import base64

mystr = 'O João mordeu o cão!'

# Encode
mystr_encoded = base64.b64encode(mystr.encode('utf-8'))
# b'TyBKb8OjbyBtb3JkZXUgbyBjw6NvIQ=='

# Decode
mystr_encoded = base64.b64decode(mystr_encoded).decode('utf-8')
# 'O João mordeu o cão!'
```

Answer (score 21):

I personally just use this Python code to decode Base64 strings:

```
print open("FILE-WITH-STRING", "rb").read().decode("base64")
```

So you can run it in a Bash script like this:

```
python -c 'print open("FILE-WITH-STRING", "rb").read().decode("base64")' > outputfile
file -i outputfile
```

**twneale** has also pointed out an even simpler solution: `base64 -d`

So you can use it like this:

```
cat "FILE WITH STRING" | base64 -d > OUTPUTFILE
#Or You Can Do This
echo "STRING" | base64 -d > OUTPUTFILE
```

That will save the decoded string to `outputfile` and then attempt to identify the file type using either the `file` tool or you can try [**TrID**](http://mark0.net/soft-trid-e.html). The following command will decode the string into a file and then use **TrID** to automatically identify the file's type and add the extension.

```
echo "STRING" | base64 -d > OUTPUTFILE; trid -ce OUTPUTFILE
```

Comment: Or "cat FILE-WITH-STRING | base64 -d" > outputfile

Comment: @twneale Of course you come along and post something simple like that :) Easier to remember than my method but no need to rewrite my scripts. I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: I had *no idea* string.decode('base64') existed. That is so cool.

Comment: Be sure to close the file handle afterwards, your first code snippet doesn't do this and someone may use it as part of a larger application.

Comment: On Mac OS X, use `cat base64-image.txt | base64 --decode > base64-image.png`

Answer (score 18):

Interesting if maddening puzzle...but here's the best I could get:

The data seems to repeat every 8 bytes or so.

```
import struct
import base64

target = \
r'''Q5YACgAAAABDlgAbAAAAAEOWAC0AAAAAQ5YAPwAAAABDlgdNAAAAAEOWB18AAAAAQ5YH 
[snip.]
ZAAAAABExxniAAAAAETH/rQAAAAARMf/MwAAAABEx/+yAAAAAETIADEAAAAA''' 

data = base64.b64decode(target)

cleaned_data = []
struct_format = ">ff"
for i in range(len(data) // 8):
   cleaned_data.append(struct.unpack_from(struct_format, data, 8*i))
```

That gives output like the following (a sampling of lines from the first 100 or so):

```
(300.00030517578125, 0.0)
(300.05975341796875, 241.93943786621094)
(301.05612182617187, 0.0)
(301.05667114257812, 8.7439727783203125)
(326.9617919921875, 0.0)
(326.96826171875, 0.0)
(328.34432983398438, 280.55218505859375)
```

That first number does seem to monotonically increase through the entire set. If you plot it:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
f, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(*zip(*cleaned_data))
```

[image]

`format = 'hhhh'` (possibly with various paddings/directions (e.g. `'<hhhh'`, `'<xhhhh'`) also might be worth a look (again, random lines):

```
(-27069, 2560, 0, 0)
(-27069, 8968, 0, 0)
(-27069, 13576, 3139, -18487)
(-27069, 18184, 31043, -5184)
(-27069, -25721, -25533, -8601)
(-27069, -7289, 0, 0)
(-25533, 31066, 0, 0)
(-25533, -29350, 0, 0)
(-25533, 25179, 0, 0)
(-24509, -1888, 0, 0)
(-24509, -4447, 0, 0)
(-23741, -14725, 32067, 27475)
(-23741, -3973, 0, 0)
(-23485, 4908, -29629, -20922)
```

Comment: @Nick T, thanks, first of all, I think the first value should be positive, because it stands for the mass of a molecule, could never be a negative value; secondly, the toal number of elements in one of these tuples shall bestly be 3, that's all what I could guess about this data, they should be mass, intensity and time respectively

Comment: it is absolutely right the mass goes in an ascending way "monotonically increase", suppose it is value on the x-axis, from 0 to an adequate maximum, whereas the intensity of this mass might vary sharply

Comment: So this is data from a GC-MS?  Try different formats, see http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html maybe `'>fhh'` or `'>fHH'`

Comment: exactlly! you are genious, for sure :)

Comment: I only used a GC-MS a few times in lab, but doesn't it just kick out an intensity vs. time plot?  Mass we had to derive from time, calibrated with some known compounds.

Comment: But you really knows it, I think the ultimate goal is to find the proteins, still halfway into it though. thanks for all your help :)

Comment: The plot is consistent with a mass spectrum of a protein digested with e.g. [trypsin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trypsin), cut after R ([arginine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arginine)) or K ([Lysine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lysine)), but not before P (mostly single-charged peptides with different masses, but also other artefacts due to the mass spectrometer type, ionisation type, etc.).

Answer (score 14):

Well, I assume you are not on Interactive Mode and you used this code to decode your string:

```
import base64
your_string = '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'
base64.b64decode(your_string)
```

Well first of all you need to assign the finished product to a variable to be able to be printed out:

```
code_string = base64.b64decode(your_string)
```

Then like any beginner programmer would know, you would print the results out:
Python 2.7x:

```
print code_string
```

Python 3.x:

```
print(code_string)
```

After the successful decoding, you will get a string about the size of the not yet decoded string. I hope this helps you!

Answer (score 4):

Note [Slipstream's response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470546/how-do-you-decode-base64-data-in-python/50602520#50602520), that `base64.b64encode` and `base64.b64decode` need a bytes-like object, not a string.

```
>>> import base64
>>> a = '{"name": "John", "age": 42}'
>>> base64.b64encode(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/base64.py", line 58, in b64encode
    encoded = binascii.b2a_base64(s, newline=False)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Answer (score 4):

Steps from Base64 to **text** ( confirmed in Linux ):

1. Import `base64` and `codecs`
2. Convert the string to `b""` using `codecs.encode(...)` and store it as a variable ( `b64Str` here )
3. Simply use `base64.b64decode(b64Str)` and store it as `resStr`
4. ( Optional ) Print `resStr`

And your code should look like:

```py
import base64
import codecs

b64Str = codecs.encode("SGVsbG8sIHdvcmxkIQ==")
resStr = base64.b64decode(b64Str)
# """
print(resStr) # Expected output: "Hello, world!"
# """
```

Comment: which version of python are you using?

Comment: Replit's latest ( 3.8 or something )

Answer (score 2):

To decode Base64 data in Python, you can use the `base64` module.

**Here is an example of how to decode a Base64-encoded string in Python:**

```
import base64

base64_string = 'QjY0RW5jb2RlLmNvbQ=='

decoded_string = base64.b64decode(base64_string)

print(decoded_string)
```

You can find a more detailed description [here](https://b64encode.com/blog/base64-in-python/).

Answer (score 1):

After decoding, it looks like the data is a repeating structure that's 8 bytes long, or some multiple thereof.  It's just binary data though; what it might mean, I have no idea.  There are 2064 entries, which means that it could be a list of 2064 8-byte items down to 129 128-byte items.

Comment: How to know that there are 2064 entries?