# Base64 Decode String in jinja

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm new to using python and flask and really like it. I'm returning a query to be displayed in a jinja template and one of my columns being returned has base64 data. How do I decode that data and display it.

Comment: this is not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470546/how-do-you-decode-base64-data-in-python, as that is about b64decoding in python, whereas this is about jinja

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In jinja To work with Base64 encoded strings:

```
{{ encoded | b64decode }}
{{ decoded | b64encode }}
```

For more http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html

Comment: It work only in ansible jinja2 implementation
https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/ed7623ecdec8585282ce91f1534d02e6a38c22a4/lib/ansible/plugins/filter/core.py#L377

Comment: Be advised that the result must be a valid UTF-8 string or you will get U+FFFE replacement characters in there. (E.g. you can't safely handle base64-encoded public keys this way.)

Comment: With StaltStack, I had to use `{{ encoded_text | base64_decode }}`, see [SaltStack Jinja docs](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/topics/jinja/index.html#base64-decode)

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer? The question is about Flask and the answer is about Ansible

Answer (score 10):

You can try to write [custom filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/#custom-filters)

```
# add filter to jinja2 env
environment.filters['b64decode'] = base64.b64decode

# in template use
{{ value|b64decode }}
```

Comment: No need for that as it is in the default filters https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#manipulating-strings

Comment: It's default filter only for ansible, not for jinja https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#list-of-builtin-filters

Comment: b64decode returns bytes but you probably want a string: `environment.filters['b64decode'] = lambda s: base64.b64decode(s).decode()`