# Base64 decode in redshift

Tags: sql, base64, decode, amazon-redshift

Is there a redshift/sql function to decode a base64 string ? 
If not please suggest me how to write a function in redshift to decode base64 ?

Comment: Please add more infos about your context

Comment: It is quite straightforward, I have a db where some data is stored in base64 encoded format and I need to show the results in decoded text format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_FUNCTION.html, You can create a function in Redshift, and you can use python to code it.

Here are some possible ways to do it in python [Python base64 data decode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470546/python-base64-data-decode)

Comment: Thanks. But you have to be a super user to create functions in redshift. Any other suggestions ?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the great suggestion. It worked. Here is my function. Only issue is that to create a function you have to be a superuser.

```
create function f_base64decode (a varchar)
  returns varchar
stable
as $$
  import base64
  return base64.b64decode(a)   
$$ language plpythonu;
```

We could check whether the programming language is trusted or not by querying the pg_language table. If it's not trusted, the lanpltrusted is FALSE

```
SELECT lanpltrusted 
FROM pg_language 
WHERE lanname LIKE 'plpythonu';
```