# Spark decode and decompress gzip an embedded base 64 string

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

My Spark program reads a file that contains gzip compressed string that encoded64. I have to decode and decompress.
I used spark unbase64 to decode and generated byte array

```
bytedf=df.withColumn("unbase",unbase64(col("value")) )
```

Is there any spark method available in spark that decompresses bytecode?

Comment: what data is stored in byte array? is it primitive datatypes( string/int/long/double/....) or custom object?

Comment: bytedf has byte array.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a udf

```
def decompress(ip):

    bytecode = base64.b64decode(x)
    d = zlib.decompressobj(32 + zlib.MAX_WBITS)
    decompressed_data = d.decompress(bytecode )
    return(decompressed_data.decode('utf-8'))



decompress = udf(decompress)
decompressedDF = df.withColumn("decompressed_XML",decompress("value"))
```

Answer (score 4):

I have a similar case, in my case, I do this:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col,unbase64,udf
from gzip import decompress

bytedf=df1.withColumn("unbase",unbase64(col("payload")))
decompress_func = lambda x: decompress(x).decode('utf-8')
udf_decompress = udf(decompress_func)
df2 = bytedf.withColumn('unbase_decompress', udf_decompress('unbase'))
```

Answer (score 1):

**Spark example using base64-**

```
import base64
.
.
#decode base 64 string using map operation or you may create udf.
df.map(lambda base64string: base64.b64decode(base64string), <string encoder>)
```

Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470546/python-base64-data-decode) for detailed python example.