# Decode content from Github API

Tags: github-api

I'm trying to make a request to the Github api and get the content (code) from a file that is in an open repo. I did a simple `curl -i` on the terminal and it returned some content that is encoded (according to the docs). How can I decode that content? And possible put the code in the correct format (indentations, etc.) when I'm outputting it on an html textarea?

Answer (score 7):

The GitHub API documentation for repository contents states that "These API methods let you retrieve the contents of files within a repository as **Base64 encoded content**." (https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/) You need to perform a base 64 decode.

Here's an example of how to do it in Python: [Python base64 data decode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470546/python-base64-data-decode)