# Converting Base64 to Hex in Redshift / python

Tags: base64, hex, amazon-redshift, decode, encode

We are migrating our database from Postgres to Redshift and we are having some challenges with converting Base64 string to Hex.

In the old situation (in postgres) we have a function :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION hex_to_int(hexval character varying)
 RETURNS integer
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
 IMMUTABLE STRICT
AS $$
DECLARE
   result  int;
BEGIN
 EXECUTE 'SELECT x''' || hexval || '''::int' INTO result;
 RETURN result;
END;
$$
```

And we call this in the select:

```
SELECT 
encode(decode('AQDAAi0EAAoFAAcN5A=='::text, 'base64'::text), 'hex'::text) AS hexresult 
FROM table
```

The result is shown as: 0100c0022d04000a0500070de4

Redshift does not seem to support plpgsql functions, now looking for a different way to do this.

[I have tried to do this with base64.b64decode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470546/python-base64-data-decode)

As a result I see:

Comment: Could you please check that your question is complete? You provided a function called `hex_to_int`, but your sample did not call the function. It appears that your requirement is to take a base64 string (eg `'AQDAAi0EAAoFAAcN5A=='`) and convert it to hex digits (`0100c0022d04000a0500070de4`) within an Amazon Redshift SELECT statement. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Amazon Redshift [User-Defined Function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_FUNCTION.html) will convert base64 into hex digits:

```
CREATE FUNCTION f_base64hexdigits (s varchar)
  RETURNS varchar
IMMUTABLE
AS $$
  import base64
  import binascii
  return binascii.hexlify(base64.b64decode(s))
$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;
```

Use it like this:

```
SELECT f_base64hexdigits('AQDAAi0EAAoFAAcN5A==')
```

Output:

```
0100c0022d04000a0500070de4
```