# How to convert base 64 encoded string back to original string again in python

Tags: python, base64

I have a string that I need to convert to base64 and send it over json via a REST API.

```
import base64

#Original string
my_string = "my_string"           #debugger=my_string

#Convert to bytes so I can base64 it
my_string_to_bytes = my_string.encode()   #debugger=b'my_string'

#Base64 it
my_string_to_bytes_to_base64 = base64.b64encode(my_string_to_bytes) #debugger = {bytes} b'bXlfc3RyaW5n'

#Convert to string or I get error TypeError: Object of type 'bytes' is not JSON serializable
my_string_to_bytes_to_base64_to_str = str(my_string_to_bytes_to_base64) #debugger = {str} b'bXlfc3RyaW5n'
```

This works and the data gets sent over the REST to my C# client and written to a text file.
Now the C# client sends the exact same data back again from text file.
I want to convert this back again to get the original string I started with.
So I start with **my_string_to_bytes_to_base64_to_str**

```
back_to_bytes = str.encode(my_string_to_bytes_to_base64_to_str) #debugger = {bytes} b"b'bXlfc3RyaW5n'"
```

But in the debugger this appends an extra 'b' onto the start of it:

```
b"b'bXlfc3RyaW5n'"
```

How can I convert the data back again to get "my_string"?

Comment: Use `.decode` instead of `str` when converting to a string.

Comment: Also when decoding: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25487483/6525260

Answer (score 1):

In this case, `str(x)` isn't doing what you think it is. It's not converting a byte string to a regular string, it's creating a string representation of the byte object.

To convert a byte string to a regular string, use the `decode` method. You may need to include a parameter to specify the encoding of the byte string, but in your specific case it should all be ASCII which is the default.

```
my_string_to_bytes_to_base64_to_str = my_string_to_bytes_to_base64.decode()
```