# base64.b64decode() output differences: Python 2 vs Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am trying to convert `python3` code into `python2` but output seems to be  different.

The code in `python2`  is:

```
import base64
crypto = 'aGVsbG8=' #=hello
s = base64.b64decode(crypto)
print(s)
```

It prints what I want: Something like- `Cs~as59 whatever`

But for `python3` the same script prints something like: `b'\x45\x67\xe3'`

Why am I getting different output for same input?

Comment: Why you are decoding non encoded data?

Comment: sry should be encoded not a actual word, updated

Comment: Put some actual encoded data so people can reproduce this locally if they would like to

Comment: The output of `b64decode` is a sequence of bytes.  In Python 2.x, that's exactly what a string was, so that's what was returned.  But in Python 3, strings are now Unicode, so things that are explicitly composed of bytes use a separate bytestring type, indicated by the `b` prefix.  Both of your outputs will be exactly the same data, just shown in two different representations.

Comment: @jasonharper how would i convert it to the python2 representation. because my script works with 2 but not 3.

Answer (score 3):

The output of the Base64 decode is now a bytestring, you can use the .decode() function to transform it into a normal string:

```
import base64
crypto = 'aGVsbG8=' #=hello
s = base64.b64decode(crypto)
print(s.decode("utf-8"))
```

This should now print the decoded string correctly.

Comment: tthe problem is it i dont think it is utf-8.... if i do utf-8 it gives an error, if i ignore error it discards some of the data