# Conversion Between Base 64 String and Byte Array Varies in C# and Python

Tags: python, c#, arrays, base64

I have a C# byte array `b_a` that has 16 byte length. When I convert `b_a` to base 64 string `aaa`, it's length returns 24

```
string aaa = Convert.ToBase64String(b_a);
Console.WriteLine(aaa.Length); //24
Console.WriteLine(aaa); //'xKKkTjcKsfBDqpIJBKn6QQ=='
```

I want to convert `aaa` string to byte array in Python. But When I convert it, it's length still returns 24.

```
aaa = 'xKKkTjcKsfBDqpIJBKn6QQ==' 
b_a = bytearray(aaa)
len(b_a) #24
```

I want to get initial `b_a` with all. What is the point that I miss?

Comment: I'm guessing that `bytearray` isn't for decoding Base64.

Comment: [Does this answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470546/python-base64-data-decode)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have base 64 encoded information, you need to decode it to get bytes. In Python 3 (and in Python 2):

```
import base64

aaa = 'xKKkTjcKsfBDqpIJBKn6QQ=='
b_a = base64.b64decode(aaa)
len(b_a)  # 16
```

Given that your code apparently works without an error, you must be using Python 2. Using `bytearray` on a `str` object in Python 3 would raise an exception because it doesn't know how to translate a string to bytes without a string encoding information. But in Python 2, `str` objects are really sequences of bytes under the hood. So `bytearray` just returns the str as bytes in Python 2:

```
>>> aaa = 'xKKkTjcKsfBDqpIJBKn6QQ=='
>>> bytearray(aaa)
bytearray(b'xKKkTjcKsfBDqpIJBKn6QQ==')
```

Comment: in your top level code, do you mean for `base64.b64decode(msg)` to actually be `base64.b64decode(aaa)`?