# How to decode python base64?

Tags: base64, decode

There are a total of 4 codes.

```
import base64, codecs

magic = 'I0ltcG9ydGluZyBNb2R1bGVzCmltcG9ydCByZXF1ZXN0cwoKI0ltcG9ydGluZyBNaSBGdW5jLi4uCmZyb20gRGF0YWJhc2UuVGltZXIgaW1wb3J0IGNsZWFyCmZyb20gRnVuY3Rpb25zLlBsYW5lciBpb'

love = 'KOipaDtXtczpz9gVREuqTRhGJScoxWiqPOcoKOipaDtGJScoxWiqNbXV1A0LKE1pjcPLJEFo2Wip3EuqUImVQ0tXPWCGxkWGxHvXDcPLJEFo2Wip3EuqUImL2uyL2gypvN9VUWypKIyp3EmYzqyqPtanU'

god = 'R0cHM6Ly9kb2NzLmdvb2dsZS5jb20vc3ByZWFkc2hlZXRzL2QvMVVQXy1oUldnSmM2clNocjU2djZ2bndLNmZqUjRGVkNsNi1xTlkwdmx6M2cvZWRpdD91c3A9c2hhcmluZycpCgojUHJvZ3JhbSBTdGF'
destiny = 'lqTIxPzAfMJSlXPxXDzSxHz9vo0uSDHESHvtcPzyzVRWuMSWiLz9mqTS0qKZtnJ4tDzSxHz9vo3A0LKE1p2AbMJAeMKVhqTI4qQbXVPNtVR1unJ5Po3DbXDbtVPNtPzIfp2H6PvNtVPOCExMZFH5SXPx='

joy = '\x72\x6f\x74\x31\x33'

trust = eval('\x6d\x61\x67\x69\x63') + eval('\x63\x6f\x64\x65\x63\x73\x2e\x64\x65\x63\x6f\x64\x65\x28\x6c\x6f\x76\x65\x2c\x20\x6a\x6f\x79\x29') + eval('\x67\x6f\x64') + eval('\x63\x6f\x64\x65\x63\x73\x2e\x64\x65\x63\x6f\x64\x65\x28\x64\x65\x73\x74\x69\x6e\x79\x2c\x20\x6a\x6f\x79\x29')
eval(compile(base64.b64decode(eval('\x74\x72\x75\x73\x74')),'<string>','exec'))
```

The first line is well decoded. However, all other codes are not decoded. How can I decode it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python base64 data decode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470546/python-base64-data-decode)

Comment: in the first example ('magic`) you found readable text. In the others you didn't find text, but that doesn't mean that the base64 decoding doesn't work, it just means that you might have wrong expectations regarding the content. In fact, the main use case for base64 encoding is to bring binary data into a form that can easily be transported in text based protocols, for example the result of encryption or hashing is typically binary and therefore often base64 encoded.