# GET API call returns non-text content

Tags: api, request

I am making an API call and reading the response in JSON

```
r = requests.get(query_url, headers=headers)
pprint(r.json())
```

But the 'content' is not in text format

```
'content': 'CmRlbGV0ZSBmcm9tICB7eyBwYXJhbXMuY3VyYXRlZF9kYXRhYmFzZV9uYW1l\n'
           'IH19LmNybS5BRkZJTElBVEVfUFJJQ0lORzsKCklOU0VSVCBJTlRPICB7eyBw\n'
           'TkcKICB3aGVyZSAxID0gMQogIAogIDsKICAKICAKCg==\n'
```

How do I convert the 'content' to text

For full context, I am trying to download code from the GitHub repo as text to store in our Database

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you decode Base64 data in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470546/how-do-you-decode-base64-data-in-python)

Comment: @CherryDT , yes that helped. I can now see all the text. Thank you for pointing me to the article

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the article @CherryDT pointed me to, I was able to get the text

```
import base64
r_dict = r.json()
content = r_dict['content']
base64.b64decode(content)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using python and in particular the `requests` package? If so, I think you could use `r.text`.

docs: https://pypi.org/project/requests/

Comment: Yes, I am using python. I tried `r.text` but I get the same content

Comment: and is the endpoint really returning a json? you may check out the headers in the response or even set the content-type header in the request